# Excel Macro for checking if a Sharepoint file is already opened

Tags: excel, vba, sharepoint

I wrote an small Macro which extends an Excel Table stored on a Sharepoint with additional rows on the bottom each day. Most of the macro is finished, however now I want to build in a loop for when the file is already opened by another user.

The process is the following:

The file is opened in read-only mode by default, which I deactivate in my code with ActiveWorkbook.LockServerFile.
After this, if another user has the file opened already, I get a pop-up window with the message that the file is locked for editing:
[image]

Is there a way for the macro to check if the file is already opened by another user and if so give me a message as a MsgBox?

Or alternatively: Is there a way to check if that window pops up and if so just end the macro with a MsgBox?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: I think you should be able to set displayalerts to false, then have VBA open the file. Then you can check for its readonly state and act accordingly.